# wait for animation to complete before hiding View

Tags: android, android-animation

I perform some things triggered by a Button click:

```
    private void onSearchPressed() {

    title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    etActionSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    etActionSearch.requestFocus();
    btnActionFavs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    etActionSearch.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getApplicationContext(), R.anim.et_anim_open));
    isSearch = true;

}
```

So basically I just hide some `Views` and show some others, my `EditText` is "sliding out" using a simple set `Animation`.

When the action is cancelled, I reverse the process:

```
    private void onSearchCancelled() {
            etActionSearch.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getApplicationContext(), R.anim.et_anim_close));
    etActionSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnActionFavs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isSearch = false;

}
```

What I'd like to do is to apply an Animation (opposite direction) to my `EditText`, so it disappears also with a slide animation. The problem is that all the code is executed immediately, so the `EditText` is gone BEFORE its animation is complete. I tried some weird things like using an `AsyncTask` and putting the animation inside the `doInBackground()` method, setting the Visibility of the `Views` in `onPostExecute()` but that didnt change anything.. `SystemClock.sleep()` also doesn't do anything but a lag impression. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Marcin Orlowski said, you have to use `AnimationListener` with your `Animation`. After the animation is ended it will launch the `onAnimationEnd()` event where you can do your stuff.

Here's a little example what i could look like:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.your_specific_animation);
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Do your hiding stuff here
        }
    });

etActionSearch.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Animations run asynchronously, so you need to use `AnimationListener` on that animation and put your code that should be executed when animation is over to `onAnimationEnd()`.

See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: thanks, it works. Accepting vilpe89's answer 'cause you are high-rep already, no offense^^